# Ubuntu bash presenting error "syntax error near unexpected token `newline'" after editing .bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I ran the command `npm completion >> ~/.bashrc` in the terminal, which made changes to my .bashrc file; now whenever the terminal is opened I receive the error:

```
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 126: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 126: `Usage: npm <command>'
```

The relevant excerpt from my .bashrc file (line 126-129) is as follows:

```
126: Usage: npm <command>
127: 
128: where <command> is one of:
129: access, add-user, adduser,...
```

which is followed by a npm command completion script.

Running `npm help` prints information on using npm in the terminal as expected (and as it did before) so that functionality hasn't changed, except now I am presented with the above warning. How do I:

1. reverse the `npm completion >> ~/.bashrc` changes with a terminal command (if so what is this command); or
2. what do I change in the .bashrc file in order to remove the warnings from my terminal?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the simplest way for you to fix this would be to run `nano ~/.bashrc` to edit the file to remove the lines at the end of the file yourself. Other editors are obviously available, but `nano` is probably the simplest to use for someone unused to the way they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `npm` command does not understand the `completion` argument and issues a help message to that effect.

The help message was then appended to your `.bashrc`:

```
 Usage: npm <command>
```

When the shell interprets that line, it effectively wants to run

```
 Usage: npm < command >
```

(The command "Usage:", with first arg "npm", stdio redirected from a file called "command" and output redirected to ... oops, **no file name after `>`**, so syntax error.

The fix is to run the proper `npm` command that does't produce a help message.

Comment: Isn't it kind of weird that npm outputs its Usage-blurb on stdout, rather than stderr? If it had, chris_p_ wouldn't have had syntax error in his .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't easily do that; it seems you have run various commands appending lines to your .bashrc, one of them npm with an option it did not understand.
2. Start your favourite text editor and remove the offending lines ("Usage:..." etc.) from the end if your .bashrc.

Comment: I removed everything below line 126 and the error was gone, and the npm help command still worked so it looks like that appendage was unnecessary. Thanks

Comment: `npm help` would always work; the purpose of running `npm completion` would be to generate the `bash` code necessary to allow tab completion of arguments to the `npm` command. However, your version of `npm` does not appear to support the `completion` command; it outputs an error message instead of lines intended to be added to `.bashrc`.

Comment: Adding stuff to .bashrc does not make "npm help" work/not work. The idea of the command you tried to run was to make "npm startofcommandTAB" do "completion" of the command. So for instance, if you wrote "npm insTAB", then bash would be able to complete that into "npm install " for you, saving some typing.